# MySQL - Count children of partents only if parent is pregnant

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: parent and children

```
--parent table:
+-------+--------+--------+
| id |  name     | active |
+-------+--------+--------+
|  1 | Júlia     |   1    |
|  2 | Constança |   1    |
|  3 | Diana     |   1    |
|  4 | Mariana   |   1    |

--child table:
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id |  idparent | pregnant  |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |   1       |   0       |
|  2 |   1       |   0       |
|  3 |   2       |   1       |
|  4 |   4       |   0       |
|  5 |   4       |   0       |
|  6 |   4       |   0       |
|  7 |   4       |   1       |
```

User 1 has 2 children and is not pregnant

User 2 is pregnant but has no children

User 3 isn't pregnant neither has children (thus doesn't appear in the children table)

User 4 has 3 children and is pregnant.

How do I count the number of parents that are pregnant and already have children?
I need to build a report that counts how many parents:

- are pregnant and have 1 child
- are pregnant and have 2 children
- are pregnant and have 3 children
- are pregnant and have +4 children

Seems easy but I can't get my head around this.
Thanks

Comment: Your data structure doesn't seem to have complete information on whether the *parent* is pregnant.  It seems to have information on whether the *children* are pregnant.

Comment: If the parent is pregnant, she will appear in the child table with field pregnant = 1. That's the tables I have to work with :(
If the parent has children, their ID appears in the child table with field parent = 0

Comment: Pregnant parent is parent and should be in table pregnant_parent!

Comment: I know, but as I said, those are the tables I have to work with. Can't modify database structure

Comment: So the pregnant will turn to a 0 when the child is born, the child is in the already in the table pre-birth with a 1 for pregnant?

Comment: The Parent is pregnant, therefore the flag should go in the Parent table. Also Pregnant does not mean successful birth, so that structure is doubly bad, as you have created a Child row before a successful birth has happened. This could lead to unfortunate email/letters going to a parent that did not successfully carry full term

Comment: Also as a rule of thumb, if your database is difficult to query to report things it is a very good indicator that the database design was flawed. The word _design_ says you should plan your database with its eventual use in mind, not hack it together as you go!

Comment: Yes Scott.
I understand what you guys are saying about the db design. The thing is, it was an outsourced web app and now I have the hot potato in hands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to get all the children already born by parent :

```
SELECT COUNT(*), idparent FROM child c WHERE pregnant = 0 GROUP BY idparent
```

Then you want all the pregnant parent :

```
SELECT p.id, p.name FROM parent p 
INNER JOIN child c ON c.idparent = p.id
WHERE c.pregnant = 1
```

And then :

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, t.nb_child FROM parent p 
    INNER JOIN child c ON c.idparent = p.id
    INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as nb_child, idparent 
         FROM child c
         WHERE pregnant = 0 GROUP BY idparent) t ON t.idparent = p.id
    WHERE c.pregnant = 1
```

As the comments above said, your model is pretty bad and I'm not sure I am answering what you want, sorry if I didn't understood.

Comment: Well, this almost works. The problem is, for example, for user 4 - Mariana, the result gives me 4 children, when in fact she only has 3 born children and 1 unborn (because sh'es pregnant).

Comment: Correction: it does work. Sorry for my rushed conclusion.

Comment: How would I modify the query to give me only the parents with 1st pregnancy? (no other children)

Comment: You need to use HAVING, if you don't find it, I will edit my answer later.

Comment: Adding HAVING COUNT(c.idparent) to the outer query? Doesn't return any results.

Comment: Hi @jean-doux. Can you please help me out? Thanks